# How do you set the frame size of cv.CreateVideoWriter

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror, computer-vision

if I try:

```
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter(file, -1,(int(800),int(600)), is_color=1)
```

-or-

```
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter(file, -1,(800,600), is_color=1)
```

-or-

```
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter(file, -1,(800.0,600.0), is_color=1)
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: a float is required

with this I get progress:

```
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter(file, -1, 25.0, (800,600), is_color=1)
```

> error: Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally.

The input files are ***.png***, the output is **.avi**

Comment: What happened to the comment with the float suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a valid *fourcc* and *fps*:

```
fourcc = cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D')
fps = 25.0 # or 30.0 for a better quality stream
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter(file, fourcc, 25.0, (800,600), is_color=1)
```

Alternatively, you can use named parameters in Python. It is less error-prone this way:

```
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter(
    filename=file,
    fourcc=cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'),
    fps=25.0,
    frame_size=(800,600),
    is_color=1)
```

A *fourcc* is an 32bit identifier of the codec of the video stream inside your target avi. Possible values for gstreamer according to [cap_gstreamer.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp) are:

```
cv.CV_FOURCC('H','F','Y','U') # HuffYUV
cv.CV_FOURCC('D','R','A','C') # BBC Dirac
cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D') # MPEG-4 Part 2
cv.CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4') # MPEG-4 Part 10 (aka. H.264 or AVC)
cv.CV_FOURCC('M','P','1','V') # MPEG-1 video
```

I believe all of the above can be put inside an avi container.

Comment: Some progress was made see above

Comment: What happened to the comment with the float suggestion?

Comment: @linuxrules94: I was wrong. You were passing your resolution pair where your fps must go. That's why OpenCv was complaining for not getting a float. I thought it also did expect floats for size values, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @linuxrules94 - There you go :) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: That's Ironic: I just sent that comment and when I did I got privilege to upvote. @junjanes

Comment: I still get errors with any of the above codecs: Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally.

Comment: @linuxrules94: Please add your OS and OpenCv version in the question.

Comment: Linux opensuse 11.4, opencv 2.2.0 See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918995/opencv-error-on-python