# Opencv error on python

Tags: python, linux, opencv, codec, computer-vision

no matter what **"CV_FOURCC"** I use I get this:

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Gstreamer
>   Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally.) in
>   CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
>   /usr/src/packages/BUILD/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp,
>   line 489

```
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter(
         filename=file,
         fourcc=cv.CV_FOURCC('F', 'M', 'P', '4') ,
         fps=iFps,
         frame_size=(800,600),
         is_color=1)
cv.WriteFrame(writer, cv.LoadImage(frames[i]))
```

Also /usr/src/packages/BUILD/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, does not exist.

Also `CV_FOURCC('H','F','Y','U')` makes empty file.

Input is ***.png**, output is ***.avi**

**Details: Opensuse 10.4, OpenCv 2.2.0**

**EDIT: If I do this this it creates a working AVI file:**

```
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter(
         filename=file,
         fourcc=cv.CV_FOURCC('F', 'M', 'P', '4') ,
         fps=iFps,
         frame_size=(800,600),
         is_color=1)
cv.WriteFrame(writer, cv.LoadImage(frames[i]))
del writer # this makes a working AVI
```

Comment: looks like a setup issue. do the tests (`<cmake_binary_dir>/bin[/debug|/release]/cxcoretest and cvtest`) work?

Comment: @mitch_feaster I didn't compile it, I installed it with YaST2

Comment: Have you tried the raw format `CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')` ?

Comment: @karlphillip Yes, it failed to work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to create a basic video file using OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781863/unable-to-create-a-basic-video-file-using-opencv)

Comment: I can't get it to work on OpenCV 2.3 either. This is a known problem from the last version. Check the comments on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781863/unable-to-create-a-basic-video-file-using-opencv/5782246#5782246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I do this this it creates a working AVI file:**

```
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter(
         filename=file,
         fourcc=cv.CV_FOURCC('F', 'M', 'P', '4') ,
         fps=iFps,
         frame_size=(800,600),
         is_color=1)
cv.WriteFrame(writer, cv.LoadImage(frames[i]))
del writer # this makes a working AVI
```

Comment: @karlphillip But if I do `cvReleaseVideoWriter(writer)` or `cv.ReleaseVideoWriter(writer)` it says "no attribute "ReleaseVideoWriter" in module.."

Comment: It's there. From your code I can't tell how you are including OpenCV but usually I do `from opencv.cv import *` and `from opencv.highgui import *`

Comment: I think you are both right, opencv.cv was a previous build of the current one, while cv is the latest. I also cant find cvReleaseVideoWriter in opencv2.3.