# Python - Using OpenCV how to stick .png's into a single mp4?

Tags: python, opencv, png, mp4

I have a directory of .png images that I want to stick into a single mp4? 
I am confident OpenCV can be used to do so, but I cannot find any resources on how exactly to? Any ideas? or tutorials?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VideoWriter to first write your mp4 to a new file, and then write your images at the tail of this file, as shown:

```
import cv2
import cv
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("your_mp4.mp4")
ret,img=cap.read()
frame1=cv2.imread("your_img1.jpg")
frame2=cv2.imread("your_img2.jpg")
height , width , layers =  img.shape     
fps=20
video = cv2.VideoWriter("rec_out.avi", cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX'), fps, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
while True: 

    ret,img=cap.read()
    height , width , layers =  img.shape
        video.write(img)
    cv2.imshow('Video', img)
    video.write(img)
    if(cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('b')):
            break

#stick your images here
video.write(frame1)
video.write(frame2)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/), you would do it like this:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i img%03d.png output.mp4
```

where:

- `-framerate` is your desired framerate (in fps)
- `-i` indicates that your images are formatted in the format `img001.png`, `img002.png` ect...
- and output.mp4 is the output file

More information [here](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow)

Comment: I have a directory of images I want stuck into a single mp4, this just does it for one, and I asked for it in Python.

Comment: This method will do it for as many images as you want, and if you had bothered to do any research, you would have found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440400/creating-a-video-using-opencv-2-4-0-in-python

Comment: Sorry, what does the 03d mean?

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff 3 digit padded decimal, i.e. 001, 002 - 200, 201 - 998, 999