# How to save a video in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have opened a Video using CV2, made some changes using `cv2.rectangle`.

Now, when I do `cv2.imshow('frame',frame)`, it plays the video.

Instead of this, I want to save the video somewhere, in the original size and frame rate.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440400/creating-a-video-using-opencv-2-4-0-in-python) may be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save video frame by frame. Based on example on docs:

[Open Cv video capture](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```