# Converting video into frames by openCV

Tags: python, opencv, frame, jupyter-lab, video-conversion

while converting video into frames , it does converted but it show this error

```
4     while success:
     35         success, frame = cap.read()
---> 36         grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     37         if(success==False and frame==None):
     38             pass

error: OpenCV(3.4.2) c:\miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv suite_1534379934306\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:253: error: (-215:Assertion failed) VScn::contains(scn) && VDcn::contains(dcn) && VDepth::contains(depth) in function 'cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper'
```

Comment: Maybe you need to change the first line to `_, frame = cap.read()`.

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52739144/3584765)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `success` variable twice, check whether the camera or video is opened:

```py
while cap.isOpened():
```

Then get the `read` outputs.

```py
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

If the frame is returned successfully, write it to the folder:

```py
if ret:
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite("output_frames/gray.png", gray)
```

Since you'll have multiple frames, you can use a counter to save each frame.

```py
count = 0

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite("output_frames/gray_{}.png".format(count), gray)
        count += 1
```

Full code:

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

count = 0

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite("output_frames/gray_{}.png".format(count), gray)
        cv2.imshow("output", gray)
        count += 1

    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: Did you change `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to the saved-video path? For instance: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\User\\..\\..\\my_video.mp4")`

Comment: my kernel is loading it is not showing anything neither it stops

Comment: When you change the path, it should be working now!

Comment: Glad, if I could help :)

Comment: i need to merge these all frame into video mp4 then how i can do that? @Ahmet

Comment: I've explained in one of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63757304/resizing-video-using-opencv-and-saving-it/63763138#63763138). Please look at that answer.