# converting gray to RGB video python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

good afternoon everybody, i would like to convert  video from gray format to color format, i  am using as  a  reference  two site, first one  is itself stackoverflow   question

[from rgb to gray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775951/how-to-convert-a-rgb-video-to-grayscale-and-save-it)

and next is opencv  site  for  cv::VideoWriter documentation, here it is
[cv::VideoWriter](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html)

on the based of this documentation, i have tried following code :

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
source =cv2.VideoCapture("test_video.mp4")
frame_width = int(source.get(3))
frame_height = int(source.get(4))
size = (frame_width, frame_height,3)
result = cv2.VideoWriter('color_version.avi',
                         cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),
                         10, size, True)
# running the loop
while True:
    # extracting the frames
    ret, img = source.read()
    # converting to color format
    colored = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    # write to gray-scale
    result.write(colored)
    # displaying the video
    cv2.imshow("Live", colored)
    # exiting the loop
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
# closing the window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
source.release()
```

sorry some part was  lost, so after running this code  i am getting following error :

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'VideoWriter'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'frameSize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3
>  - Argument 'fps' can not be treated as a double
>  - Can't parse 'frameSize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3
>  - VideoWriter() missing required argument 'params' (pos 6)
```

from the official site i  have indicated   bool isColor=true  and therefore  it should accept  3D format right? please help me what is wrong with  my code

Comment: The size parameter just needs width and height, not the number of channels (3).

Comment: then it gives following error : > Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 3

Comment: Why do you think the frames you get from `source` (which is an mp4 file) are grayscale ? I.e. why do you need `COLOR_GRAY2RGB` ?

Comment: because i have downloaded  specificly   video in gray format

Comment: The fact that the content is grayscale doesn't mean the frame you got from the mp4 decoder is 1 channel. Did you verify that `img` contains only 1 channel ?

Comment: actually it is  3D i have checked, but i dont want to delete  question, in case of i got  1 channel images from  video, how to make it  3 channel images?

Comment: even if the video itself were gray, OpenCV will convert that to BGR while decoding, unless instructed otherwise using flags/properties. both `imread()` and `VideoCapture` behave like that.

Comment: Dear  @ChristophRackwitz thank you for your time  and feedback, i have watched once    a  TV  broadcast, where  it was talk about converting old black and white  movies  to the colorfull ones, therefore  if  i have  a   video which contains gray frames and i want to convert it to the color ones, then what  to do?because if decomposition of original gray video is done into  color images, than we dont need to convert by ourself and directly saving to the  new video format will be enough? i know that we can  do Histogram Equalization, but if i need to  change colors? for instance HSV? then?

Comment: grayscale data does not contain color information. conversion to RGB/BGR merely reproduces grayscale using three equal amounts of color, which looks gray. -- recolorization requires AI. this exceeds the scope of the question and requires *research* on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL:DR** OpenCV's `VideoCapture` will always convert the image to BGR for and it's `VideoWriter` expects frames in BGR format. Also, the video format you chose (MJPEG) doesn't support RGB (or BGR) and will internally save images in (subsampled) YUV format. As a result, you don't have to do anything extra to process gray video; it "just works".

If you still wish to access the data in its raw pixel format, you can do so in python, but not via OpenCV. For this, you'd either use pyav or ImageIO.

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio

# General Note: ImageIO returns 8-bit RGB frames by default.

# read frames in their raw/native format
# will fail if pixel format is not stridable
frames = iio.imread("test_video.mp4", format=None)

# force grayscale result (convert if necessary)
frames = iio.imread("test_video.mp4", format="gray")

# read frames one-by-one
for frame in iio.imiter("test_video.mp4", format="gray"):
    ...  # do something useful
```

That said, the odds of finding a video that uses grayscale internally are very, *very*, **very** low. If you do find one, please reach out to me if you can share it publically. I'd love to add it to our test suite (I maintain ImageIO).

---

**Long Version**

The way you would handle this in OpenCV is to not worry about the pixel format of your raw input video. OpenCV will convert to BGR for you and you have no influence on this behavior in 99.9% of the cases.

There is also no reason to go from BGR to RGB unless you want to process the frames outside of OpenCV and you *know* that the external pipeline expects frames in RGB. The `VideoWriter` expects frames in BGR format, so passing RGB to it will result in a discolored (misscolored?) result.

```py
import cv2

source = cv2.VideoCapture("test_video.mp4", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
frame_width = int(source.get(3))
frame_height = int(source.get(4))
size = (frame_width, frame_height)
result = cv2.VideoWriter(
    "color_version.avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"), 10, size, True
)
# running the loop
while True:
    # extracting the frames
    ret, img = source.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # converting to color format
    colored = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    ... # external processing in RGB
    colored = cv2.cvtColor(colored, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    # write to gray-scale
    result.write(colored)
    # displaying the video
    cv2.imshow("Live", colored)
    # exiting the loop
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
# closing the window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
source.release()
```

In the 0.01% of cases where you actually *can* have some control over the pixel format is when you are using VAPI to read frames from a generic webcam or are grabbing frames from a specialist camera using the XIEMA backend. This doesn't help much here though, because not only does this not apply to files, but it also doesn't change the fact that openCV will *still* convert to BGR in the end. (The mean idea behind having this feature anyway is that you can control the bandwidth of your camera stream.)

If you want to explore what is possible using the OpenCV API yourself, I invite you to check out OpenCVs [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3f22f4727cbd3168df9e5dfdcf531277c766819e/modules/videoio/include/opencv2/videoio.hpp#L183) where you can find all the config options for video IO.

---

For good measure, here is how the same program would look like using ImageIO:

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio

# extract the FPS from the source video
fps = iio.immeta("test_video.mp4")["fps"]

with iio.imopen("color_version.avi", "w") as file:
    file.init_video_stream("mjpeg", fps=fps, pixel_format="yuvj420p")
    for frame in iio.imiter("test_video.mp4"):
        # frame is converted to RGB by default
        ... # external processing
        file.write_frame(frame)
```

Comment: Please remove ban  from asking question, i have not idea  why it  was blocked, i  am  always asking questions, logical questions, trying to show my work  and it is not  fair and  humann way to  block  me from asking questions, please remove ban as  quickly as possible.

Comment: @AIresearcher I have no influence on the moderation decisions made here on SO, so I unfortunately don't think that I can help in this regard.